# Is String a immutable class in JAVA, So how to use this feature is multi-Thread programing?

Tags: java, string, multithreading, thread-safety

```
public class Test {  
    public static String str = "abc";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("before run" + str);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                       Thread.sleep(100);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {;}

                    str =str +"1";
                }
            }).start();
        }
        System.out.println("after run" + str);
    }
}
```

I did a test for immutable class String, it is a thread safe class so I guess I dont have to do the synchronized stuff

But it shocks me when the result shows up with 
"before abc" and "after abc".

and when i removed those Thread.sleep(100); the result became
  "before abc" and "after abc1111".

the public static String str is  modified, why?

Comment: You're not modifying the *string*, you're modifying the *variable* referencing it. Why would that stock you?

Comment: I don't see you are able to modify values of string (like "before run")... Indeed you can change value of a variable... but it has nothing to do with type being immutable...

Comment: You're not mutating a String (as Strings are immutable, this would be impossible). You're assigning a new string to the static variable. That has nothing to do with immutability and threads. Only to the possibility to do `String s = "a"; s = "b";`.

Comment: If you wanted to make sure `str` doesn’t change, you can do so by declaring it final: `public static final String str = "abc";`.

Answer (score 0):

Immutability means you can't change the content of an object. With a mutable object (such as array, ArrayList, Date) you can change what that object holds. But with strings you can't do that. Your example shows replacing a reference to one object with a reference to a different object.

To disallow this replacement make the variable final.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I misunderstand the meaning of 'Immutability'

Answer (score 0):

> public static String str is modified, why?

**It did not modify the same `String` object**, rather the reference variable `str` points to a different object (in the string constant pool maintained by JVM) each time when you are performing a concatenation (+) operation i.e., the existing string object will be discarded.

With Immutability, you can't change the existing object content once created, which is good when it comes to thread safety i.e, you don't need any explicit synchronization/locks to safeguard the object across multiple thread writes/reads.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you can modify an immutable object like String, but you can change the reference variable to point to different string like how you are doing.

You see the difference in output because, when the sleep method is removed or commented some of the threads out 5 threads run fast enough so that the str variable reference is updated to point to the concatenated string. That is the reason, when you run this program by removing sleep method, you might see different output as shown below.

```
after abc1
after abc11
after abc1
after abc
```

But, when the sleep method is not removed, your main thread waits completes even before all other threads finish, and that is how you see mostly "after abc" as output as the concatenation might not happen by the time main thread reach that last print statement. But, if you reduce the sleep time to 5 milliseconds and like that you may see the output some times as "after abc1".

So, basically the output depends on how fast the main thread reaches the last print statement and it is nothing to do with the string being Immutable or not